# Невозможно удалить элемент из бд

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Возник вопрос. 
Во время добавления элемента (объекта) в БД всё работает и отображается как положено. 
Но как только возникает необходимость удалить элемент из БД. 
Возникает следующая ошибка:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'UserRole' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'RoleId', 'UserId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Интерфейс пользователя выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрагмент проблемного кода представлен ниже:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var result = (from user in db.Users
                      from userRole in user.UserRoles
                      where userRole.Role.UserRole == UserRole.User
                      orderby user.FullName ascending
                      select user);

        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        //Проставить всех пользователей в checked, если у них есть роль UserRole.ProjectMgr
        foreach (User user in result)
        {
            Person p = new Person { UserId = user.UserID, FullName = user.FullName, Mail = user.Mail };

            db.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.UserRoles).Query()
                .Include(ur => ur.Role)
                .Load();

            bool @checked = user.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr);


            if (@checked)
                p.Checked = @checked;

            persons.Add(p);
        }

        return View(persons);
    }


    //Отметка людей как ProjectMgr
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetProjectMgr(int[] checkProjectMgr)
    {
        //Присвоим роль пользователя при регистрации
        Role role = db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr);

        foreach (User user in db.Users)
        {
            //Подгружаем роли пользователя
            db.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.UserRoles)
                .Query()
                .Include(ur => ur.Role)
                .Load();

            //для роли пользователя
            MSIE.Data.ManyToManyEntities.UserRole userRole = new Data.ManyToManyEntities.UserRole
            {
                Role = role,
                User = user
            };

            //Проверяем наличие роли ProjectMgr
            bool isInRole = user.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr);

            //Проверяем список пользователей для назначения им роли ProjectMgr
            if (checkProjectMgr.Contains(user.UserID))
            {
                //Если в человека есть уже эта роль ProjectMgr, то не добавляем
                //Иначе добавляем эту роль
                if (isInRole)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    user.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
                    db.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
                }

            }
            //Убираем роль ProjectMgr, у тех пользователей, которые не отмечены
            else
            {
                if (isInRole)
                {
                    user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
                    db.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

Детальный скрин ошибки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую ASP.NET Core MVC v 2.2 
В методе `Index` пробовал использовать `AsNoTracking()`, а в методе `SetProjectMgr(int[] checkProjectMgr)` для экземпляра `userRole` использовал: `db.Entry(userRole).State = EntityState.Detached;` и `db.UserRoles.Attach(userRole);` - результата никакого и проблема осталась

С чем это может быть связано?

Считаю, что это вопрос может быть полезен разработчикам работающих с EF и ASP.NET Core MVC

Спасибо за уделённое время и внимание.

Comment: Опишите словами логику, которую вы хотите сделать. У вас приходит набор int[] айдишников пользователей. Вы обходите список пользователей и для тех кто попал в ваш список добавляем роль проектного менеджера, а для тех, кто не попал - удаляем. Верно?

Comment: @AK абсолютно верно.

Comment: У вас как-то неоптимально написан запрос... грузить всю базу пользователей (допустим, миллион?), чтобы потом пару галок "менеджер" добавить, ещё одну снять и вообще менеджеров - десяток из миллиона. Вы не хотите сделать выборку пользователей, кто является менеджером и обойти тех, кому сняли галку, а потом обойти пользователей базы, у кого в базе нет галки а в int[] появилась? Я почему предлагаю - потому что думаю, что вашу проблему вообще снимет как рукой и не нужно будет разбираться, какая сущность криво добавилась.

Comment: @AK миллион уж точно не будет, и даже 1000 и даже 100. 
Правильно понял. Необходимо создать два интерфейса для пользователя, где:
В 1-м: Работать с менеджерами, т.е. удалять их роль.
Во 2-м: Добавлять пользователей в список менеджеров. Назначать им такую роль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Вопрос может быть закрыт. Всем спасибо за советы и участие. 

Изменения коснулись метода `SetProjectMgr`
Этапы решения данной проблемы:

1. Если задаём новую роль `Role` для пользователя `User`, то необходимо создать новый объект `UserRole` и добавить бд.
2. При удалении роли `UserRole.ProjectMgr`, необходимо отыскать данную роль в пользователя `userRole = user.UserRoles.SingleOrDefault(ur => ur.Role.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr)` и удалить её в `db.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);`.

В предыдущей (старой) версии метода `SetProjectMgr` создавался новый объект `UserRole` для каждого `User`, следовательно при добавлении всё работало отлично.

Но, при удалении `UserRole` выполнялась попытка найти и удалить несуществующий (новый созданный) объект в бд, что приводило к ошибке в строке `db.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);`.

Также был выполнен рефакторинг кода в данном методе.

Сам код метода приведён ниже:

```
    //Отметка людей как ProjectMgr
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetProjectMgr(int[] checkProjectMgr)
    {
        //Присвоим роль пользователя при регистрации
        Role role = db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr);

        MSIE.Data.ManyToManyEntities.UserRole userRole;

        foreach (User user in db.Users)//await db.Users.ToListAsync())
        {
            //Подгружаем роли пользователя
            db.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.UserRoles)
                .Query()
                .Include(ur => ur.Role)
                .Load();

            //Проверяем наличие роли ProjectMgr
            userRole = user.UserRoles.SingleOrDefault(ur => ur.Role.UserRole == UserRole.ProjectMgr);

            //Проверяем список пользователей для назначения им роли ProjectMgr
            if (checkProjectMgr.Contains(user.UserID))
            {
                //Если в человека есть уже эта роль ProjectMgr, то не добавляем
                //Иначе добавляем эту роль
                if(userRole != null)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    //для роли пользователя
                    userRole = new Data.ManyToManyEntities.UserRole
                    {
                        Role = role,
                        User = user
                    };
                    //user.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
                    db.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
                }
            }
            //Убираем роль ProjectMgr, у тех пользователей, которые не отмечены
            else
            {
                if (userRole != null)
                {
                    //user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
                    db.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй перед удалением выполнить

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Comment: `else{
 if (isInRole)
 {
user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
 db.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
db.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);
}
else
 continue;
}` 
Не сработало. Та же ошибка.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что здесь происходит, но похоже как будто эта строчка user.UserRoles.Add(userRole); 
лишняя. 
Два раза пытаешься удалить роль.

Comment: то есть вот эта 
user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);

Comment: В методе `SetProjectMgr` удалил: `user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);`
Результат - та же ошибка.